# SImple functions queue in python

Tags: python, queue

I would like to run a function once other functions have terminated executing. In this example I would like `live_departure_board()` to run after `a_live_departures()` and `b_live_departures()` have finished running and have successively saved data to a JSON. The reason is that function `live_departure_board()` needs to the JSON generated by the other two.

I've read that I could use `queue` but was wondering if there was something simpler for my use case.

Here is how are they called:

```
def get_livedepartures():
    a_live_departures()
    b_live_departures()
    live_departure_board()
```

Comment: Can't you call them in order in your python script?

Comment: Are `{a,b}_live_departures` running in separate threads?

Comment: I've just added details on how I call them. They do are in order but from the log I see that live_departures_board is running before the other ones.

Comment: The effect you describe is not straightforward Python.  Normally, one statement finishes execution entirely before the next one begins.  `b_live_departures` will not get called until `a_live_departures` returns, and *that* won't happen (normally) until `a_live_departures` has completed execution.  `b_live_departures` has to return before `live_departure_board` can get called.  We'll need your MCVE to figure out what's happening to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you do:

```
a_live_departures()
b_live_departures()
live_departure_board()
```

As I understand python does things in order. If you need b_live_departures() while you do live_departure_board() you could look into threading.

Comment: I was hoping that too, but when I run them I can see from the console that live_departures_board is firing before the other ones. The other functions scrape data from the web, process it and then write it to a JSON.

Comment: add print statements into the others to check if they are running first.

Comment: Thanks - for some strange reason I was calling it in the wrong place. Putting print in all functions helped.